# Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php

creo que muchos de vosotros habéis visto el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

He hecho de todo, cambiar versiones leer muchos foros y pues nada. Tengo las siguientes extensiones habilitadas en el `php.ini`

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

En el `error.log` no sale nada relacionado, sólo el error mismo:

> [Wed Mar 15 18:18:35.602697 2017] [:error] [pid 8080:tid 1728] [client
>   ::1:49291] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
>   sqlserv_connect() in...

Como podéis observar el `phpinfo.php` no se ve mal. Haber si alguien me puede dar una mano. Os agradecería inmensamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: in... ¿Puedes mostrar el fragmento de código en donde te da ese error y qué manejador de dase de datos estás usando (MySQL, SQL Server u otro)?

Comment: no tienes una sección sqlsrv en tu phpinfo? Digo, porque lo que muestras es la extensión pdo_sqlsrv y no es lo mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LO QUE A MI ME PASO**
Utilicé los drivers de Microsoft y no funcionó.

**COMO LO SOLUCIONÉ**
1. Descargué los drivers "No Oficiales" de
http://robsphp.blogspot.pe/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html
2. En el zip, están los drivers para PHP de 32 y 64 bits.

**COMO INSTALARLOS (MUY IMPORTANTE LEER BIEN)**

1. Copiar los DLL's a la carpeta ext de PHP.

   - Los DLL deben ser la misma version con el PHP instalado
   - Los DLL deben coincidir con PHP si este es TS o NTS
2. En PHP.INI agregar las siguientes líneas al final de la sección de extensiones:

   - extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
   - extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

   > OJO: El nombre del archivo DLL debe ser del cual se está instalando, en este ejemplo es para PHP 5.6 TS
3. Guardar el PHP.INI y reiniciar servicio apache

> NOTA: Yo estoy utilizando SQL Server 2016 SP1 y me funciona normal, Suerte.

Comment: Hola como estas? estamos haciendo los mismos pasos pero ni siquiera aparece en el phpinfo. Nos podras dar una mano? tenemos el ultimo XAMPP con PHP Version 7.1.6

Comment: @BraianMellor, no funciona con php 7.1, aunque hay cierta manera de "hacerlo funcionar", podriamos intercambiar la informacion por una via mas activa y funcional

Comment: Por favor. Decime como queres hacer que estamos realmente trabados. Gracias

Comment: ¿Me podrían decir cómo hacerlo funcionar en PHP 7.16? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

tenia un problema similar resulta que utilice el xampp v3.2.4 con la versión de php 7.4.11 y los driver no oficiales son para php 5 al 5.5
probé este y me funciono

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x86.dll

de SQLSRV 3.0. para php 7 en adelante, probé este y me funciono
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2120362
de SQLSRV 2.0.  soporte paraor PHP 5.2 y/o PHP compilado con VC6

Answer (score -1):

No necesariamente es por el tema de que los drivers sean firmados o no, lo que sucede habitualmente es que no descargamos el driver correcto.

Para que esta Brujería funcione es necesario que revises la versión de PHP que tienes, en tu caso 5.6, por ende debes descargar del sitio oficial de microsoft la librería correcta. En el caso de PHP 5.6 debes descargar el dirver de microsoft que tiene la terminación 32, para la versión PHP 7 debes usar la librería con terminación 40

Después sigue las instrucciones de este manual http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

y para realizar la conexión lo que me fincionó a mi es el siguiente ejemplo:

//declaramos la función que realiza la conexión a la BDD

```
function OpenConnection()  
{  
    try  
    {  
        $serverName = "nombre de la instancia"; 
        $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"nombre de la BDD",  
            "Uid"=>"usuario del SQL", "PWD"=>"El PAsword"); 
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);  
        return $conn;
        /*
          //en mi caso no reconoce la función FormatErrors() por eso lo 
            comenté
        if($conn == false)  
            die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));  
        */
    }  
    catch(Exception $e)  
    {  
        echo("Error!");  
    }  
}  
//Esta función genera ejecuta una consulta cualquiera
    function ReadData($tsql)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        $conn = OpenConnection();  
        $tsql ;  
        $getNames = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);  
        /*if ($getNames == FALSE)  
            die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));  */
        $productCount = 0;  
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getNames, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
        {  
            echo($row['nombre']);  
            echo("<br/>");  
            $productCount++;  
        }  
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($getNames);  
        sqlsrv_close($conn); 

    }  
    catch(Exception $e)  
    {  
        echo("Error!");  
    }  
}
```

//aquí mandamos llamar la función colocando la consulta como parámetro

```
ReadData("SELECT algo FROM algunaTabla")  ;
```

Espero a alguien le sirva yo tardé días en comprender la nueva forma de conexión a SQL SERVER de PHP