# Conectar PHP con SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server

Buenos días tengo una duda, ya que tengo una base de datos en ***SQL SERVER*** 2014 y estoy intentando establecer una conexión desde ***PHP*** ya lo revise y según yo mi error esta al mandar llamar la dirección ***IP*** del servidor de base de datos pero desconozco si estoy omitiendo algo.

```
<?php
$serverName = "1.1.1.1"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Example", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida satisfactoriamente.<br />";
}else{
     echo "No se pudo establecer la conexion.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

El error que me manda es este:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Gracias nuevamente por su ayuda.

Comment: PHP por defecto no integra funciones para conectar con SQL Server, tendrás que cambiar el lenguaje de programación o usar librerías de terceros. Saludos.

Comment: La función no existe, es decir, necesitas instalar la [extensión `SQLSRV`](http://php.net/manual/es/sqlsrv.setup.php) Lee detenidamente los `Requerimientos` antes de ver cómo instalarla.

Comment: Mirad este link, info sobre como solucionar ese error:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55719/32600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LO QUE A MI ME PASO**
Utilicé los drivers de Microsoft y no funcionó.

**COMO LO SOLUCIONÉ**
1. Descargué los drivers "No Oficiales" de
http://robsphp.blogspot.pe/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html
2. En el zip, están los drivers para PHP de 32 y 64 bits.

**COMO INSTALARLOS (MUY IMPORTANTE LEER BIEN)**

1. Copiar los DLL's a la carpeta ext de PHP.
2. Los DLL deben ser la misma version con el PHP instalado
3. Los DLL deben coincidir con PHP si este es TS o NTS
4. En PHP.INI agregar las siguientes líneas al final de la sección de extensiones:
   A. extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
   B. extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

> OJO: El nombre del archivo DLL debe ser del cual se está instalando, en este ejemplo es para PHP 5.6 TS

5. Guardar el PHP.INI y reiniciar servicio apache

> NOTA: Yo estoy utilizando SQL Server 2016 SP1 y me funciona normal, Suerte.

Comment: como puedo saber si es ts o nts? tengo instalada la version 5.6 de php que viene con xampp?

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar adoDB o Laravel (o algun framework parecido que permita configurar el driver para conectar con SQL Server...) para conectar PHP con SQL Server.

https://laravel.com/
http://adodb.org

A parte, no te recomiendo usar el usuario sa para conectar con la instancia sql... mejor crea un usuario para hacer esto y asignale dbowner.

Un saludo.

Comment: Ok lo voy a revisar, gracias.