# ¿Por qué me aparece error sqlsrv_connect?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli, odbc

Buen día mi duda es saber por qué me dice lo siguiente en mi página web

> **Error fatal : Error no detectado: Llamada a la función no definida sqlsrv_connect () en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ IVAMEX2 \
>   templatemo_491_flat \ conexion_sis.php: 4 Seguimiento de pila: # 0
>   {main} arrojado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ IVAMEX2 \ templatemo_491_ \
>   conexion_sis.php en la línea 4**

Mi código PHP es este:

```
<?php
$serverName="localhost";
$connetioninfo= array("Database" => "prueba_usuarios", "UID" => "user", "PWD" =>"password","CharacterSet"=> "UTF-8");
$con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connetioninfo);

if($con){

   echo "conexion exitosa"; 
}else{

echo "fallo en la conexion";
}

?>
```

Comment: Es probable que no tengas instalado el controlador `sqlsrv`, lo podrás comprobar ejecutando `phpinfo()` y viendo allí qué módulos están instalados.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv\_connect()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55679/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect)

Comment: ya lo intente y agrege

Comment: las extensiones que me pide junto con als que tengo registradas 

extension-php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension-php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension-php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension-php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

Answer (score 0):

Significa que la extensión de sqlsrv no está habilitada o instalada en tu php. Revisa si la tienes instalada en tu xampp, solamente es habilitarla; de lo contrario tendrás que instalarla.

Comment: me sigue apareciendo error y ya las agrege al php ini y a php ext

extension

Comment: extension-php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension-php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension-php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension-php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll