# Undefined function in PHP

Tags: php

Esta es una conexión a SQLServer. Me sale este error y no logro resolverlo. Gracias por la ayuda.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\update\0_sqlserver_to_csv.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\update\0_sqlserver_to_csv.php on line 9

````
$serverName = "****";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "****",
    "Uid" => "****",
    "PWD" => "****"
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection to SQLServer failed: " . sqlsrv_errors());
}

$sql = "SELECT SKU, Price_MN FROM SQLServerView";

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die("Request to View failed: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Process -->>

// <<-- Process

// Close connection

sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>```
````

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: read https://www.php.net/manual/es/sqlsrv.installation.php

Comment: Es probable que tu servidor no tenga instalada la extensión de sql_server

Comment: tienes un post relacionado con el mismo error https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55679/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect